# Two post increment questions

Tags: c#, post-increment

I have this code :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        int c;

        //task A
        c = a;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        c = a++;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        Console.WriteLine(c);


        //task B
        c = b;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        c = b++;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        c = b;
        Console.WriteLine(c);

        Console.ReadLine();  

    }
```

the output is:

task A

```
1 1 1
```

task B

```
1 1 2
```

**Task A question**

I expected the result from task A are 1 1 2 because while at second write resulting 1 because post increment, but shouldn't it become 2 now at third write?

**Task B question**

I expected the result from task B are 1 1 1 because although at second part it is post increment, but shouldn't it become 1 at third write because int b = 1 and c = b?

Thanks.

Comment: Please use debugger and watch values carefully while stepping through the code. Your expectations are unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Task A**

The result is 1 1 1 because a becomes **2** after the assignment, and c retains the assigned value, which is **1**.

1) a = 1 , c = 1

2) a = 2 , c = 1 (a is post-icremented)

3) a = 2 , c = 1 (c is not changed)

**Task B**

The result is 1 1 2 because the second assignment sets c = 1 (b's value before the increment), while the third assignment sets c = 2 (b's value after the increment from the previous assignment)

1) c = 1 , b = 1

2) c = 1 , b = 2 (b is post-incremented)

3) c = 2 , b = 2 (c is assigned b's value)

Answer (score 3):

In your first case, this line is important:

```
c = a++;
```

That will work in two steps:

1. Assign current value of `a` to `c` (`c` is now 1)
2. Increment the value of `a` by one (`a` is now 2)

Since the value of `a` isn’t assigned to `c` *after* it’s being incremented, `c` doesn’t know about that new value and remains `1`.

In your second case, you do assign `a` to `c` *after* `a` was incremented. So in the last step, `c` gets the value of the new `a` which is 2.

Keep in mind that a post (or pre) increment *changes* that variable. So in `c = a++`, `a` *changes* after the line is executed, making all future references to `a` use that incremented value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happens in detail:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c;

//task A
c = a;   // c is now 1
c = a++; // a is 1 at assignment so c is 1
         // after assignment, a becomes 2; this does not impact c

//task B
c = b;   // c is now 1
c = b++; // b is 1 at assignment so c is 1
         // after assignment, b becomes 2; this does not impact c
c = b;   // c is now 2
```

The main point to understand is that when you assign a primitive to a variable, it is assigned the primitive's value. In case of objects, both variables would point to the same object, but in case of primitives, the value is copied. Any modifications on variable 1 will not be reflected in variable 2.

Answer (score 0):

Is the expected behavior: `a++` will give you the value from `a`, the increment will be done after. `++a` is what you are looking for. Also, native variables (int, char, float, double) get value assignment, not reference with the `equal` operator.

Comment: I understand in a++ increment will be done later and that's why I put second write at task A to see it become 2 but the problem it's not.

I understand ++a but the problem is I want to understand a++ perfectly.